# AttributeError: 'LargeList' object has no attribute 'reader'

Tags: python

Hello guys im learning how to code doing this small code creating a method to read a csv file I have object has no attribute mistake, can you help me please?

```
import csv

class LargeList:
    def readCsv(self, filename):
        with open(filename) as fp:
            reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter = ",", quotechar = '""')
            for row in reader:
                print(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    csv = LargeList()
    filename = 'N.csv'
    csv.readCsv(filename)
```

Comment: When you did `csv = LargeList()`, you overwrote the `csv` module you imported earlier.  Chose a different variable name here.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I use this for working with csv files:

```
import csv


def open_csv(path):
'''return a list of dictionaries
'''
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        return [dict(row) for row in reader]

print(open_csv('./test.csv'))
```

Input csv:

```
first_name,last_name,email
John,Doe,john.doe@example.com
Jane,Doe,jane.doe@example.com
Foo,Bar,foo.bar@example.com
```

Output:

```
[{'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Doe', 'email': 'john.doe@example.com'}, {'first_name': 'Jane', 'last_name': 'Doe', 'email': 'jane.doe@example.com'}, {'first_name': 'Foo', 'last_name': 'Bar', 'email': 'foo.bar@example.com'}]
```

I've learned to let the csv package handle format parsing on its own, its pretty awesome at that!